# Bind two models

Tags: django, django-models

I need something like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    torrents = # Link to torrents in group


class Torrent(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    group = # Link to group
    name = models.TextField()
    hash = models.TextField(max_length=32)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and next in code:

```
group = Group.objects.create(id=123, name="Test group")
# some code...
Torrent.objects.create(id=321, group=group, name="Test torrent", hash="hash")
```

then:

```
Torrent.objects.get(id=321).group.torrents.all()
```

What I need to use? ForeginKey in `Torrent` to group and ManyToMany in `Groups` to torrents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [**`related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). `related_name` allows you to  reverse query from `Group` to `Torrent`.

So, I think your relationship should be like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()


class Torrent(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='torrents', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField()
    hash = models.TextField(max_length=32)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a `ForeignKey` relation from `Torrent` to `Group`, which means:

> *`Torrent` has a group, therefore one `Group` may have multiple related torrents.*

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()


class Torrent(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='torrents')
    # _________________________________________________________^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    name = models.TextField()
    hash = models.TextField(max_length=32)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Focus on the `related_name` attribute here. This is how you fetch the reversed relation (`group.torrents`).